# There is two boxes with one with 8 balls and one with 4 balls

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

We have two boxes:
$A$ - with two 8 balls, and $B$ - with 4 balls.
we choose randomly box and pull out a ball.
We do it again and again until box $B$ will be empty.

**What is the probability that box $A$ is empty?**
(When we choose $B$ and see it empty).

I'm stuck and I don't have any idea how to begin to solve this problem....

I know that I need to calculate $P(E|F)$, where $E$ = Box $A$ is empty, $F$ = Box $B$ is empty.

Thank you!

Comment: The question is rather oddly posed. What happens if box $A$ is empty and we pick box $A$ again? It should simply ask, "What is the probability that box $A$ is emptied before box $B$?"

Answer (score 1):

$A$ will be empty if it has been picked eight or more times in the first 11 rounds.

Probability of picking $A$ exactly 8 times out of 11: $\binom{11}{8}2^{-11}$
Probability of picking $A$ exactly 9 times out of 11: $\binom{11}{9}2^{-11}$
Probability of picking $A$ exactly 10 times out of 11: $\binom{11}{10}2^{-11}$
Probability of picking $A$ exactly 11 times out of 11: $\binom{11}{11}2^{-11}$

Adding these up: $$(165 + 55 + 11 + 1)2^{-11} = \frac{29}{256}$$

Comment: But why is the $2^{11}$? And why you not add more, and where is the picking of $B$??... It's really seems that you right, but there is few things that are unclear to me... Thank you!!!

Comment: $2^{11}$ should be $2^{-11}$. Thank you for pointing that out! I have corrected it.

Comment: You're welcome!! And I still not understand why the $2^{-11}$...

Comment: @Yoar: Read the first sentence again.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to find out what my lecturer meant and I'll tell you... I hope it will be tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

When *B* is empty, the possibilities are you have done from four "picks" (you hit the *B* every time) to 8 + 4 = 12 "picks" (you hit *A* at least 8 times before taking the last ball from *B*, for which you must have hit *B* three times before). You could not have done more or less "picks".

So there are 9 possibilities (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 "picks"), and the question is: "what is the probability that you will have done 12 "picks" (which is the only outcome in which *A* is empty)?" The answer seems simple, the probability for one out of nine possible outcomes is 1/9, right?

Right?

(This answer is purposefully incomplete, It's meant to give you a start on the solution but not to give you the complete answer. So now, try to solve the problem considering what I've written, and if you still can't figure it out, I'll post the whole solution in a few hours).

**Addition**

When *B* has been emptied, there are 9 possible "amounts of picks" that could have got you here. But all these are not equally likely, for example: there is only one way to empty *B* in four picks, namely by picking *{B, B, B ,B}*. But there are several ways of emptying *B* in five picks, to name two: *{A, B, B, B, B}*, *{B, A, B, B, B}*. So to calculate the likelihood of emptying *B* in 12 picks, one would have to find out how many "ways" that one can be done, versus the summarized "ways" of all the other 8 amounts of picks. One way to find this out would be by hand, but perhaps you can fins a pattern or formula for computing "how many ways can you order (for instance) five *B's* and two *A's*?"

**Addition II**

Well, see Graham Kemp's comment for the rest of the solution, I think he did a great job.

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, there must be $12$ picks, right? any other number of picks will not make the condition of the question (i.e. we A and B are empty).
So, I make new event: there was 12 picks?|

Thank you! And I'd like to see your full solution!

Comment: That is correct, you did understand me right. However, to solve the problem fully, you also have to ask yourself "are all numbers of picks equally likely?" And that is what I'd like you to consider before I post my full solution.

Comment: But how the question "are all numbers of picks equally likely?" helps me? I will really glad if you can give me one more clue for this... Thank you!!!

Comment: Added some more info, hope this will let you see the solution. I really hope you will be able to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: Well, there's only 1 way to end after 4 picks; all from box B.  There's 4 ways to end after 5 picks; 1 pick from A and 3 from B in any order, then pick from B. There's $\frac{5!}{3!2!}$ ways to end after 6 picks. Et cetera... There's $\frac{(n-1)!}{3!(n-4)!}$ ways to end after n picks.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes, exactly. However, I have to say that the asker's own answer is more elegant than mine, assuming one knows what a _Bernoulli experiment_ is.

Comment: @Graham: that's right as far as it goes. But you still don't say how to compute the probability. For instance, the probability of ending after 5 picks is not 4 times the probability of ending after 4 picks, because a specific 5-pick sequence is half as likely as a specific 4-pick sequence.

Comment: This problem is easier than you are making it out to be $-$ see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand:
It's a **Bernoulli Experiment**:
$$X\sim Bin\left(12,\frac12\right)$$
When $X$= "the box we choose".
We have to caluculate: $P(X=4)$ (At 12 times that we make this experiment we have to choose box $B$ 4 times ("success") and box $A$ 8 times ("failed")).
So the result is:
$$P(X=4)=\binom{12}{4}\cdot \left(\frac12\right)^4\cdot \left(\frac12\right)^8=\frac{495}{4096}$$

Comment: No, that's wrong, for two reasons: (i) you also need that the 12th pick is $B$; (ii) you must also allow for the fact that box $A$ may be picked _more_ than 8 times. See my answer.

Comment: @TonyK, Why? after the boxes are empty I can pickup $A$ how much I want, what matter is when I pick $B$ and it's empty, $A$ will be empty also... About the second - I'll try to find out, but I think that if we pickup $A$ and it's empty it's like "we didn't do the experiment" i.e. - We don't count it. Whats matter it's only when $B$ is empty... (then we have to if $A$ is empty too...).

Comment: Like I said, see my answer. Do you agree with my logic? If so, yours must be wrong.